# Save As functionality in shiny app download

Tags: r, download, shiny, shinydashboard, save-as

I am building a shiny app where I am trying to put a download button which will ask user to choose name while saving the file. In below example, when user clicks on download button, it automatically downloads the file without asking user for the filename.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Downloading Data"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Choose dataset ----
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),

      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tableOutput("table")

    )

  )
)
server
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)
  })

  # Table of selected dataset ----
  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Let me know if anyone has some idea.

Comment: Use a modal dialog to take the filename as input?

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic way to take in file name. It does need another TextInput

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Downloading Data"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Choose dataset ----
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),
      textInput("file_name_input", "enter file name",placeholder = "Default"),

      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tableOutput("table")

    )

  )
)
server
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)
  })

  # Table of selected dataset ----
  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
     paste(input$file_name_input, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I am looking for a save as functionality, As you may have seen in many websites/ pages/apps. when User clicks on download, there opens a pop-up which provides browse option for location.

Comment: Yes, I figured that’s what you wanted. However I am not aware of any native shiny capability to do that. It may require some JavaScripting.